# Setup with Kubernetes hostPath but file doesn't show up in container

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set up `hostPath` to share a file between pods.

I'm following this guide [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

Here are the configuration files for `pv,pvc,pod`.

PV:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/tmp/data"
```

PVC:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

POD:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        name: task-pv-storage
```

I'm adding a file to `/tmp/data` and but I can't see it in the container.

When I check the status of `pv,pvc,pod`, the result is as following:

[image]

Can some give me a clue on why I can't see the file? Any suggestion or command on how to debug this kind of issue is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figure it out. 
HostPath is only suitable for a one-node cluster. my cluster have 2 nodes. so the physical storage the PV use is on another computer.

when I first go through the documentation, I don't pay attention this:

"You need to have a Kubernetes cluster that has only one Node"

Answer (score 15):

**MINIKUBE specific**

I was getting the same error when running a local cluster on minikube for Mac.

Minikube actually creates a VM and then runs your containers on it. So the hostPath actually refers to paths inside that VM and not on your local machine. That is why all mounts show up as empty folders.

Solution:

Map your local path to minikube's VM by same name. That way you can refer it as is in you kubernetes Manifests.

```
minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>
```

In this case:

```
minikube mount /tmp/data:/tmp/data
```

This should do the trick.

SOURCE: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/

Comment: According to the minikube documentation, keep in mind that depending on the mount folder, your data may or may not be there if the minikube VM restarts.

For instance using the folder /data* inside the minikube VM promises persistance, whereas if you used /tmp/exampleDir/ it may not.

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/

Comment: or just use `minikube ssh -n <node-name>` to jump into the vm.

Answer (score 0):

did you put a local file in `/tmp/data` in the first place ?

Comment: yes. I put file in it and create new file in container. you can checkout my own answer below, I made a silly mistake.

Comment: definitely, hostpath PV are not "distributed". it works well in minikube for testing though

Comment: There is a new volume type `local`, which is a better `hostpath` volume, because you can define to which node it belongs, and the pod consuming it will only be scheduled on that node. So that will work on a multinode cluster. Still not recommended for production use, because when the node fails, you have a problem ;) See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local